# HTML\CSS Unused Whitespace

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I'm working on a website and I have a lot of unused whitespace on the sides. I can't figure out which property to edit to get rid of it. If I could utilize that space I could move my elements around better. I posted a picture to illustarte how much white space I have on the side, and what I'm shooting for when I get rid of the space. If I need to post any code I can. [image]

wrapper encases the entire body

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.5%; /*First value is top/bottom, second is left/right*/
}
```

pair is the class the divs are held in

```
.pair {
    float: left;
    border:10px solid #002233;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 5% 0;
}
```

Comment: Any code would be appreciated. For start, you can try `float:left` for those divs.

Comment: I would also recommend reading a little about `display: inline-block`

Comment: adding display:inline-block does nothing to the div. I tried putting that but no luck.

Comment: The first issue I see: `max-width: 940px;` Your container will never be wider than 940px. Also, post your HTML.

Comment: @disinfor yep of course it was the max-width...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'problem' is your wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 2.5%; /*First value is top/bottom, second is left/right*/
}
```

It sets the `max-width` to 940px and centers the content with the `margin: 0 auto;`

Try to use the `float: left;`-idea with the following code:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 2.5%; /*First value is top/bottom, second is left/right*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` on the big `<div>`s.

**Before Float**

```css
.block {width: 30%; margin: 1% auto;}
.block img {max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

**After Float**

```css
.block {width: 30%; float: left; margin: 1%;}
.block img {max-width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

Comment: I float the divs left and they only go as far as in the image. I added code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be sorta responsive according to the screen width, then I would use float property.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="yourClass">
        <img src="#" alt="#" title="#" />
    </div>
    <div class="yourClass">
       <img src="#" alt="#" title="#" />
    </div>
    <div class="yourClass">
       <img src="#" alt="#" title="#" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS ( You can adjust the container and img width which suits your site design )

```
.container { max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto }
.container>* { padding: 10px }

.yourClass { float: left }
.yourClass img { width: 460px; height: auto } /* will resize your images according to the width you want the image be in your site, this will ensure consistency in your design */
```